soapMessage.getAttachments(); Missing End Boundary for Mime Package : EOF while skipping headers
I have a problem when I receive a SAAJ message from an external service, with two attachment,
first is:
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
and second Content-Type: text/plain
Content-ID: <patch.txt>   here is the attached txt file, for example
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
and when in the code I use
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage;


@Service
public class ProcessingService {

public List<String> processSoapMessages(List<SoapMessage> soapMessages) throws JAXBException {

        soapMessages.forEach(soapMessage -> {

            var attachments = soapMessage.getAttachments();

and when I enter the soapMessage.getAttachments(); line in the debugger, I get an error:
"Missing End Boundary for Mime Package : EOF while skipping headers"
I tried different options with soapmessage casting
SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) soapMessage;
I tried also to set property to ignore it
System.setProperty("saaj.mime.multipart.ignoremissingendboundary", "true");
I also tried to use Apache, but later methods must be in Spring
The request that comes to me has good boundary and I am not able to change it, any ideas?
